# call the desired methods from the jar file

Tags: java, jar

below is my java file, and  i'm exporting the same an separate jar file ,name of the jar is "Softassert"

```
package com.annuity_payer;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Map;

import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.Reporter;

import com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleneseTestBase;

public class Softassert extends SeleneseTestBase {
    private StringBuffer verificationErrors;
    private StringBuffer verificationSuccess;

    public Softassert() {
        verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();
        verificationSuccess = new StringBuffer();
    }


    public void verifyEquals(String actual, String expected, String msg) {
        try {
            Assert.assertEquals(actual, expected, msg);
            verificationSuccess.append(msg + ":" + " " + "Actual Result:" + " "
                    + actual + " " + "Expected Result:" + " " + expected
                    + " - Condition PASSED" + "\n");

        } catch (AssertionError e) {
            verificationErrors.append(e + "-Condition FAILED" + "\n");          
        }
    }
}
```

so then i'm creating an new project and the jar file is mapped with build path to retrieve an method from the jar file

below are the code

```
   import com.annuity_payer.Softassert.*;

    public class testJar {
        Softassert prabu = new Softassert();
        prabu.verifyEquals("test","test","verification");
```

from that above i'm creating an object name of "prabu", then try to call desire method (i.e verifyEquals method)
when i try the same its shown an error "syntax error on tokens" Please clarify / help how to call the method from my jar file

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the star in the import if you only want to import "Softassert", use...

```
import com.annuity_payer.Softassert;
```

If you want all classes in the annuity_payer package, you can use

```
import com.annuity_payer.*;
```

You might be getting confused with "import static" statements

Comment: Thank Breat, but still i'm getting the same error message

Comment: @Prabu Could you clarify 'when i try the same its shown an error "syntax error on tokens"' Could you update your post with the exact error message and show what line this is occurring on? Does it only happen in your IDE or are you building form the command line?